# How to connect api.ai for chatbot with web service in android?

Tags: android, chatbot

How to connect api.ai for chatbot with web service in android?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the complete sample for API.ai for Android [Here](https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-android-client)

For Web & other samples, check here on [Github](https://github.com/api-ai)

Hope this will help. Happy Coding.

Comment: I need voice integration by using chatbot?

Comment: Check out the sample, which has voice integration too. Refer the first link. I have personally tested it, which works fine.